# Как отключить автозапуск сервера postgresql

Tags: база-данных, windows, postgresql

Возможно для кого то этот вопрос будет достаточно простой, однако для меня непонятно где и как можно отключить авто-запуск сервера. Если с командами `pg_ctl` я разобрался и хочу исключительно с их помощью запускать и останавливать сервер, а авто-запуск, который настраивается при установке СУБД `postgresql 10`,
отключить. Как мне лучше это сделать? (Сервер на Windows и нужен исключительно для локального использования) Гугл не помог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайти в **`Службы`** через поиск `Windows` или через `Win+R` и вызывать `services.msc`.

И там найти `postgresql-x64-12`. Правой кнопкой мыши, и там выбирайте `Остановить` или `Запустить`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если необходимо выключить в автозапуске. То изменяйте вариан запуска здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]